# Replace values in certain rows based on value in different row

Tags: r, replace

I have run into the following problem: due to a programming mistake, I had to change my rating scale from -4 to +4 to a scale from 0 to 9 temporarily. This results in 8 values in my data frame that I want to recode based on the ID that is defined in a different column.

```
id selfassessment
202 5
203 5
204 7
205 8
206 9
207 7
208 6
```

So for only those 8 rows in 'selfassessment' I want to change the values with 5 to 0, 6 to 1, 7 to 2, 8 to 3 and 9 to 4 without changing anything for the rest of the column.
Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: There are 7 rows here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df$selfassessment <- df$selfassessment - ifelse(df$selfassessment>=5, 5, 0)
```

Comment: glad to be of assistance! One thing: when you have a second, would you mind accepting the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

`df$selfassessment <- ifelse(df$selfassessment<5, 0, df$selfassessment-5)`

Comment: thank you! This helps for the rows in question but overwrites everything else in the column. As I said, most of the columns were already coded in the right way. I only need to recode those specific rows.

Comment: Do you need to apply this formula for specific id'S or specific selfassesment interval ?

Comment: for specific id's